# Checking if the input-password was correct

Tags: c++, memory, passwords, password-protection, password-encryption

My program was only for me until now. 
I got asked to make it public for my school, but since now i just compare useriname and password like

if inputu == username && inputp == password

but then i head about hooking and stuff to read out the memory and if i compare it like this it should be really easy to get access.

I have no idea about making it save, I heard about "hashing" the pw and then hash the input too with the same algorithm and compare the hashs but cant you read out the algorithm too?

I have no idea, thank you for help!

Comment: *"but cant you read out the algorithm too?"* Yes, but that doesn't mean your program is insecure. Consider that RSA and ECDSA are open cryptographic algorithms, and they are also considered secure. Good cryptographic algorithms are secure *in spite of* being known.

Comment: if someone wants to break your password, he will do it. Why do you want to make it safe? What is the purpose of that password?

Comment: What you'd want to do is use a encryption algorithm like `sha512`. You take the users password append a `salt` to it and then run it through the `sha512` algorithm and then store that as their password. Then when they login again you follow the same steps and compare the saved encrypted password to the typed in one.

Comment: @GaryJohnson Don't forget the detail of storing the salt with the hash, that's a pretty important thing to omit.

Comment: because it downloads stuff from a "secret" site and only persons with access to the pw may see this. i just recognized that the web-page is stored as an string too -.-

Comment: 1. Code is a MAIN way communicating between programmers. 2. Use interpunction (dots, commas), Your post is unreadable

Comment: Which book are you using to learn computer security?

Comment: Im not using any book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security, cryptographic hashes are very fast. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash.

Use functions such as `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

> References:

See [How to securely hash passwords, The Theory](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846) on Security Stackexchange.

See OWASP (Open Web Application Security Project) [Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Leverage_an_adaptive_one-way_function).

See [Modern, Secure, Salted Password Hashing Made Simple](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016#legacy-hashes)

Protecting your users is important, keep in mind that users will use the same password on many sites, if your passwords are compromised that may the users on other sites. Please use secure password methods.

> Books:

[*Handbook of Applied Cryptography*](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/index.html) by Alfred J. Menezes, Paul C. van Oorschot and Scott A. Vanstone, see free download

[*Cryptography Engineering*](https://www.schneier.com/books/cryptography_engineering/) by Niels Ferguson, Bruce Schneier, and Tadayoshi Kohno

[*Applied Cryptography*](https://www.schneier.com/books/applied_cryptography/) by Bruce Schneier

[*Cryptography Decrypted*](http://www.informit.com/store/cryptography-decrypted-9780201616477) by H. X. Mel and Doris M. Baker (good starter I really like)

Comment: thank you very much, i have an idea now where i can start!